# Building a view with arguments from a search select list

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a block with custom search options based on taxonomy terms (hierarchical dropdown).
When you submit the form, it renders the ID of the taxonomy terms. I want to have a query in another block on the same page which renders all nodes containing the taxonomy terms.
How can I link the IDs?
Is this possible to do it with Views? Should I build a custom view through a hook, or is there another way to achieve this goal?

I am using the 7.x-3.x-dev version of Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the block display, add a *contextual filter* for your taxonomy term field. Set it to *Provide a default value* when *the filter value is not in the URL*. Use *Taxonomy term ID from URL* as *type* for this default value and select *Load default filter from term page*.